# Per frame optimization for large datasets

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, optimization, core-data, binary-tree

#### Summary

New to iPhone programming, I'm having trouble picking the right optimization strategy to filter a set of view components in a scrollview with huge content. In what area would my app gain the most performance?

#### Introduction

My current iPad app-in-progress let's users explore fairly large binary tree structures. The trees contain between 30 to 900 nodes, and when drawing inside a scrollview (with limited zoom) it looks like this.

[image: Screenshot of tree exploration app]

The nodes' contents are stored in a SQLite backed Core Data model. It's a binary tree and if a node has children, there are always exactly two. The x and y positions are part of the model, as are the dimensions of the node connections, shown as dotted lines.

#### Optimization

Only about 50 nodes fit the screen at any given time. With the largest trees containing up to 900 nodes, it's not possible to put everything in a scrollview controlled and zooming UIView, that's a recipe for crashes. So I have to do per frame filtering of the nodes.

And that's where my troubles start. I don't have the experience to make a well founded decision between the possible filtering options, and in addition I probably don't know about that really fast special magic buried deep in Objective-C or Cocoa Touch. Because the backing store is close to 200 MB in size (some 90.000 nodes in hundreds of trees), it's very time consuming to test every single tree on the iPad device. Which is why I'd like to ask you guys for advice.

For all my attempts I'm putting a filter method in the scrollViewDidScroll: and scrollViewDidZoom:. I'm also blocking the main thread with the filter, because I can't show the content without the nodes anyway. But maybe someone has an idea in that area?

Because all the positioning is present in the Core Data model, I might use NSFetchRequest to do the filtering. Is that really fast though? I have the idea it's not a very optimized method.

From what I've tried, the faulted managed objects seem to fit in memory at once, but it might be tricky for the larger trees once their contents start firing faults. Is it a good idea to loop over the NSSet of nodes and see what items should be on screen?

Are there other tricks to gain performance? Would you see ways where I could use multi threading to get the display set faster, even though the model's context was created on the main thread?

Thanks for your advice,
EP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ironically your binary tree could be divided using [Binary Space Partitioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning) done in 2D so rendering will be very fast performant and a number of check close to minimum necessary.

Comment: Hey @too, thanks, I'm having a hard time seeing ways to implement BSP in my 2D environment case, but that Quadtree looks promising. Seems like there's a more optimal hit test with the view port in there, but it looks like heavy stuff...

Comment: A few days into the heavy stuff, you were indeed correct on the binary space partitioning, I just couldn't figure out how this worked until I saw that what I implemented based on the QuadTree idea, was, in fact Binary Space Partitioning. Long story short, thanks, on the spot!